# How to write unit test for a method which takes no parameters and use a mongoTemplate to Query

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, mongotemplate

I am trying to write the unit test for a method which does not take any parameter and inside it uses a mongoTemplate to query using criteria. Let me post the entity class first

```
 @Data
 @Builder
 @Getter
 @Setter
 @NoAgrsConstructor
 @EqualAndHashCode
 public class MyInventory{

  @Id
  private String id;
  @Field("it_key")
  @JsonProperty("it_key")
  private String it_key;

  ............
```

In my service class it is feching data using the below method

```
  public List<MyInentory> getAllData(){
  Query query = new Query();
  //some criteria here
   query.addCriteria(criteria);
  List<MyInventory> listOfInventory = mongoTemplate.find(query,MyInventory.class);
  return listOfInventory;
}
```

I am trying to write the unit test for it

```
  @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
  @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
  @MockitoSettings(strictness=Strictness.LENIENT)
  @SpringBootTest(classes={MongoTemplate.class}
  @ActiveProfiles("mock")
  public class MyInventoryServiceTest{
 
   @MockBean
   private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

   @Test
   public void testGetAllData(){

   mockMyInentoryList.add(MyInventory.builder()
    .id("614a4d70cghyt86")
    .it_key("DESS")
   //.........setting the data here 
   .build()
 );

 List<MyInventory> expected = new ArrayList<>();
 Inventory inv = Mockito.mock(MyInventory.class);
 expected.add(inv);
 when(this.mongoTemplate.find(any(Query.class),eq(MyInventory.class)))
.thenReturn(mockMyInentoryList);
 Assert.asserEquals(mockMyInentoryList,expected);
```

And the error what i get is

```
 java.lang.AssertionError

 Expected:[MyInventory(id=614a4d70cghyt86,it_key=DESS........]
 Actual:  [Mock for MyInventory, hashcode: 1252142274]
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to verify in this test. I would expect the test to call `getAllData()` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `getAllData()` in your test and verify that the results returned match the results returned from the mocked Mongo template:

The test will look something like this:

```
@Test
public void testGetAllData() {
    MyInventoryService myInventoryService = new MyInventoryService(mongoTemplate);

    List<MyInventory> mockMyInventoryList = new ArrayList<>();
    mockMyInventoryList.add(MyInventory.builder()
            .id("614a4d70cghyt86")
            .it_key("DESS")
            //.........setting the data here
            .build()
    );

    when(this.mongoTemplate.find(any(Query.class), eq(MyInventory.class)))
            .thenReturn(mockMyInventoryList);
    Assert.assertEquals(mockMyInventoryList, myInventoryService.getAllData());
}
```

Comment: mongoTemplate is always null;

Comment: This code doesn’t make any changes to how `mongoTemplate` is defined. If you had that working before, something else must have changed.

Comment: arraylist cannot be returned by tostring() i am getting this always

Comment: That sounds like an unrelated problem. You should post a new question with the relevant code if you’d like help with it.